# Bootstrap custom validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrapvalidator, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

I'm trying to use 1000hz bootstrap validator to add custom validation for emails, I want to generate validation if the value of email field is repeated in another field.

Here is my code so far:

```js
var filledEmail = [];
  function checkEmailDup(email) {
    document.querySelectorAll("input[type='email']").forEach(mailField => {
        const emailVal = email.value;
        const hasMail = filledEmail.find(x => x === emailVal);
        if (!hasMail) {
          filledEmail.push(emailVal);
          console.log("Valid Email");
          return true;
        }
        else {
          console.log("Invalid Email");
          return false;
        }
        console.log('filled mails without duplicates', filledEmail)
    });
  }
  
  
$('#myForm').validator({
  custom: {
    'emaildup': function ($el) {
    if (checkEmailDup($el)== false) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
}
  },
  errors: {
    'emaildup': "Nope"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" name="rental-app-form" role="form" class="multisteps-form__form" data-toggle="validator">
<input id="applicant-email" required data-table="Applicant email address" data-emailDup="true"  data-emailDup-error="Enter a unique email" data-pattern-error="pattern error" data-required-error="Please enter a valid Email address." name="applicant-email" type="email" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" placeholder="Email address">
<input id="parent-1-email" required data-table="Parent 1 Email Address" data-emailDup="true"  data-emailDup-error="Enter a unique email" data-error="Please enter a valid Email address." name="parent-1-email" type="email" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
<input id="parent-2-email" required data-table="Parent 2 email" data-emailDup="true"  data-emailDup-error="Enter a unique email" data-error="Please enter a valid Email address." name="parent-2-email" type="email" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
<input id="landlord-email" required data-table="Landlord email address" data-emailDup="true"  data-emailDup-error="Enter a unique email" data-error="Please enter Email address." name="landlord-email-a" type="email" class="multisteps-form__input form-control nameF" placeholder="Email address">
<input name="employer-email-a" data-table="Employer email" data-emailDup="true"  data-emailDup-error="Enter a unique email" data-error="Please enter a valid email address" type="email" class="multisteps-form__input form-control" placeholder="Email Address(optional)">
<button class="btn btn-success ml-auto" type="submit" title="Send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

when I type anything in the input field nothing happens at all

Comment: Your `<input>` and `<button>` need to be inside a `<form>`

Comment: You also add an event inside an event, so will add another one each time you validate

Comment: When then also makes it clear that `checkEmailDup()` has no return value as the return true/false are inside the change event handler

Comment: But it's not even getting that far as `data-` attributes must be all lower case.

Comment: So adding `<form id=myform` and changing `emailDup` to `emaildup` (and all the data-emailDup`) as well as removing the addEventListener line at least gets the validation running.  Next, move the filledEmail=[] inside checkEmailDup and you've got a good starting point.

Comment: I will try that thank you!

Comment: I've tried what you said and the validation is working but it's always invalid
This is what the console returns after waiting for some seconds:
Valid Email
script.js:12 Invalid Email
script.js:8 Valid Email
script.js:12 Invalid Email
script.js:8 Valid Email
script.js:12 Invalid Email

Comment: I don't get what am I doing wrong as this function worked perfectly if called normally